# Replace Electret Microphone With Arduino Output

Tags: arduino, audio, signal, microphone, electret

I have the following circuit for a simple FM transmitter.

[image: schematic]

I want to replace the electret microphone with a simple tone generated by an Arduino (or equivalent) that will be broadcast over FM radio.

**Qns:**

1) Is this possible to do?

2) How would I go about doing this? (E.g. will a PWM signal from a digital I/O port on the Arduino work?)

3) Maybe there is a simpler way to broadcast a simple tone over FM radio?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. YES
2. I'd use an IO port with a low pass filter and feed it directly into C1 (left hand side)
3. What you have is fairly simple

It's probably illegal what you want to do so check out the legislation applicable to your country.